# Create global ProgressDialog

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog, progressdialog

I have created common function for displaying custom progressbar in another class. When i call this function Dialog box will be shown but when i want to dismiss that Dialog box than it could not be dismissed. Here is the code

```
public void showPopupProgressSpinner(Boolean isShowing) {

        Dialog progressDialog;
        ProgressBar progressBar;

        progressDialog = new Dialog(context);
        progressDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        progressDialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup_progressbar);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) progressDialog.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        progressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#ff6700"),
                android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);

        if (isShowing == true) {
            progressDialog.show();
        } else if (isShowing == false) {

            progressDialog.dismiss();

        }
    }
```

This is how i call this function
**To show dialog box**

```
utils.showPopupProgressSpinner(true);
```

**To Hide dialog box**

```
utils.showPopupProgressSpinner(false);
```

Comment: because everytime you create new dialog, define progress dialog globally

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.. Can you please more elaborate it ? @justDroid

Comment: Dialog progressDialog; define this outside of showPopupProgressSpinner method.

Comment: Thanks @justDroid now it works fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this it works for me.

```
private Dialog progressDialog = null;
private ProgressBar progressBar;

public void showPopupProgressSpinner(Boolean isShowing) {
    if (isShowing == true) {
        progressDialog = new Dialog(AndroidVideoCaptureExample.this);
        progressDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        progressDialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup_progressbar);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(
                new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) progressDialog
                .findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        progressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(
                Color.parseColor("#ff6700"),
                android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        progressDialog.show();
    } else if (isShowing == false) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You saved my lots of time buddy.. Thanks a ton